# Connecting to QNetworkReply::error signal

Tags: qt, qt5

I am using the new connect syntax for Qt5. QNetworkReply has a signal called [error](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qnetworkreply.html#error-2) and also a function called [error](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtnetwork/qnetworkreply.html#error). This causes problems when attempting to connect to the signal:

```
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::error, this, &MyClass::error);
```

> error C2664: 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char *,const QObject *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'overloaded-function' to 'const char *'
>   Context does not allow for disambiguation of overloaded function

How do I tell the compiler (MSVC) that I want to connect to the signal rather than the function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting overloaded signals and slots in Qt 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794695/connecting-overloaded-signals-and-slots-in-qt-5)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need manually to cast the function pointer to address the correct function:

```
connect(reply, static_cast<void (QNetworkReply::*)(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)>(&QNetworkReply::error), this, &MyClass::error);
```

This is the [noted](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) consequence of using new syntax for overloaded functions:

> cons:
>
> Very complicated syntax in cases of overloads?

P.S. You can find similar example on the above link:

```
 QObject::connect(socket, static_cast<void (QTcpSocket::*)(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)>(&QAbstractSocket::error), [socket] (QAbstractSocket::SocketError) {
        qDebug()<< "ERROR " << socket->errorString();
        socket->deleteLater();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Start from **Qt 5.15** `QNetworkReply::error` is not a signal any more. You can connect to [`&QNetworkReply::errorOccurred`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#errorOccurred) instead, fortunately, without type casting:

```cpp
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::errorOccurred, this,
            [reply](QNetworkReply::NetworkError) {
               qCDebug() << "Error " << reply->errorString(); 
            });
```