# QT overloaded signal in QComboBox cannot connect to slot

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, signals-slots

I want to use slot-signals stuff without SLOT() & SIGNAL() macroses, as explained [here](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/signalsandslots.html) - exactly, I want to implement this part

```
QObject::connect(&a, &Counter::valueChanged, &b, &Counter::setValue);
```

In example above - slot and signal taking no arguments.

My real-life example:

```
connect(m_subsystemComboBox, &QComboBox::currentIndexChanged, this, &CMainWindow::ComboBoxChange);
```

Catch here is following - [QComboBox::currentIndexChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#currentIndexChanged-2) is overloaded to accept QString and int.
And by using example above - I get following error from visual studio

```
IntelliSense: cannot determine which instance of overloaded function "QComboBox::currentIndexChanged" is intended
IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "CMainWindow::connect" matches the argument list
        argument types are: (QComboBox *, <unknown-type>, CMainWindow *, void (CMainWindow::*)(const QString &str))
```

I have tried to append (QString) to functions in connect() - another error:

```
IntelliSense: expression must be an lvalue or a function designator
```

Could anyone help me to achieve connection of currentIndexChanged signal with QString to my slot?

Comment: `CMainWindow::ComboBoxChange` accept `QString` or `int` too?

Comment: How do you "overload" the QComboBox::currentIndexChanged signal? Please show the code.

Comment: You seem to be connecting the signals and slots the other way around. The syntax is `object, signal, object slot` not `object, slot, object signal`.

Comment: @pezy nope, only QString.

Comment: @thuga right, fixed, however, error remains the same

Comment: @vahancho I did not overload anything, it's already overloaded - I've made a link to QT docs on submitting question.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794695/qt5-overloaded-signals-and-slots).

Comment: @thuga thanks, exactly what I need, will search better next time!