# Qt5 Signal/Slot syntax w/ overloaded signal & lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, qt5

I'm using the new syntax for Signal/Slot connections.  It works fine for me, except when I try to connect a signal that's overloaded.

```
MyClass : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    void setup()
    {
        QComboBox* myBox = new QComboBox( this );
        // add stuff
        connect( myBox, &QComboBox::currentIndexChanged, [=]( int ix ) { emit( changedIndex( ix ) ); } ); // no dice
        connect( myBox, &QComboBox::editTextChanged, [=]( const QString& str ) { emit( textChanged( str ) ); } ); // this compiles
    }
private:

signals:
    void changedIndex( int );
    void textChanged( const QString& );
};
```

The difference is currentIndexChanged is overloaded (int, and const QString& types) but editTextChanged is not.  The non-overloaded signal connects fine.  The overloaded one doesn't.  I guess I'm missing something?  With GCC 4.9.1, the error I get is

```
no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::connect(QComboBox*&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, MyClass::setup()::<lambda()>)’
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting overloaded signals and slots in Qt 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794695/connecting-overloaded-signals-and-slots-in-qt-5)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to explicitly select the overload you want by casting like this:

```
connect(myBox, static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), [=]( int ix ) { emit( changedIndex( ix ) ); });
```

Since Qt 5.7, the convenience macro [`qOverload`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload) is provided to hide the casting details:

```
connect(myBox, qOverload<int>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), [=]( int ix ) { emit( changedIndex( ix ) );
```

Comment: Cheers... not sure if the rather convoluted makes the pros worth it or not yet... but at least I know!.