# Error while connecting lambda function to QProcess::error

Tags: qt, c++11, lambda, qprocess

In following code I want to connect lambda function to QProcess::error signal:

```cpp
void Updater::start() {
    QProcess process;
    QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::error, [=] (QProcess::ProcessError error) {
        qWarning() << "error " << error;
    });
    process.start("MyProgram");
    process.waitForFinished();
}
```

But I get strange error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'Updater::connect(QProcess*
>   [unresolved overloaded function type],
>   Updater::start()::)' });

What I do wrong here? The code executes inside method of class derived from QObject. The project configured to work with c++11.

I use Qt 5.3.1 on Linux x32 with gcc 4.9.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting overloaded signals and slots in Qt 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794695/connecting-overloaded-signals-and-slots-in-qt-5)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem is that the `QProcess` has another [`error()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#error) method, so compiler just doesn't know which method use. If you want to deal with overloaded methods, you should use next:

```
QProcess process;
connect(&process, static_cast<void (QProcess::*)(QProcess::ProcessError)>
(&QProcess::error), [=](QProcess::ProcessError pError) {
    qWarning() << "error " << pError;
});
process.start("MyProgram");
process.waitForFinished();
```

Yes, it looks ugly, but there is no another way (only old syntax?).

This special line tells compiler that you want to use `void QProcess::error(QProcess::ProcessError error)`, so now there is no any ambiguity

[More information you can find here](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/16795664/846250 for a small snippet to make the overload declaration "automatic"

Comment: Finding that `static_cast` requirement was a tricky one, thanks.

Comment: Just a side-note: same applies to the `finished` signal: `static_cast<void (QProcess::*)(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)>(&QProcess::finished)`. Gotta love C++ spaghetti syntax. LOL

Answer (score 1):

For those who are using Qt 5.6 or later, the `QProcess::error` signal is deprecated. You can use the `QProcess::errorOccurred` signal instead to avoid the naming ambiguity and complicated casting.

```
QProcess process;
connect(&process, &QProcess::errorOccurred, [=](QProcess::ProcessError error) {
    qWarning() << error;
});
process.start("MyProgram");
process.waitForFinished();
```