# C2665: 'QObject::connect' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the arguments types

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, lambda, signals

I have the following code in main

```
         QProcess process;
        QObject::connect(&process, &QProcess::error, [](QProcess::ProcessError error)
        {
            qDebug() << error;
        }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
        bool launched = process.startDetached("D:\temp.exe");
```

and it is generating this error while compiling

```
    D:\main.cpp:5: error: C2665: 'QObject::connect' : none of the 3 overloads could convert all the argument types c:\qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\include\qtcore\qobject.h(205): could be 
'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char
    *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType) const' c:\qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\include\qtcore\qobject.h(201): or 
      'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const QMetaMethod &,const QObject *,const QMetaMethod &,Qt::ConnectionType)' c:\qt\5.3\msvc2013_64\include\qtcore\qobject.h(198): or      
 'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect(const QObject *,const char
    *,const QObject *,const char *,Qt::ConnectionType)' while trying to match the argument list '(QProcess *, overloaded-function, RunGUIMode::<lambda_5d6e7ee926a623cea2a0e4469253d55f>, Qt::ConnectionType)'
```

can someone please help me out and tell me what i am doing wrong.

I want to connect a signal from the `QProcess` class to my lambda

Comment: Turns out to be answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331859/error-while-connecting-lambda-function-to-qprocesserror

Comment: Also Qt::QueuedConnection somehow prevents this compilation as well. I initially started doing the same but could not understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I shouldn't post this answer, but to be honest it is not [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31331859/error-while-connecting-lambda-function-to-qprocesserror), it is more complex.

First of all, why first version doesn't work. Because you can't use additional argument (connection type) without providing `receiver`. It means that next is wrong.

```
connect(&process, static_cast<void (QProcess::*)(QProcess::ProcessError)>
        (&QProcess::error),[=](QProcess::ProcessError pError) {
        qWarning() << "error " << pError;
},Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

But next is correct:

```
connect(&process, static_cast<void (QProcess::*)(QProcess::ProcessError)>
        (&QProcess::error), this , [=](QProcess::ProcessError pError) {
        qWarning() << "error " << pError;
},Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

If you wonder why, look at the `qobject.h`. I make some changes in this file, just to be more accurate (don't change this file!).

```
//first
//connect to a functor
template <typename Func1, typename Func2>
static inline typename QtPrivate::QEnableIf<QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::ArgumentCount == -1, QMetaObject::Connection>::Type
connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal, Func2 slot)
{
    qDebug("There is no here argument for connection, isn't it?");
    return connect(sender, signal, sender, slot, Qt::DirectConnection);
}

//second
//connect to a functor, with a "context" object defining in which event loop is going to be executed
template <typename Func1, typename Func2>
static inline typename QtPrivate::QEnableIf<QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func2>::ArgumentCount == -1, QMetaObject::Connection>::Type
connect(const typename QtPrivate::FunctionPointer<Func1>::Object *sender, Func1 signal, const QObject *context, Func2 slot,
        Qt::ConnectionType type = Qt::AutoConnection)
{
    qDebug("This will be called, and as you can see you need specify the context if you want to use connection type.");
    //...
```

Secondly when you run this code, you will get:

> QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type
>   'QProcess::ProcessError' (Make sure 'QProcess::ProcessError' is
>   registered using qRegisterMetaType().)

So you need add `qRegisterMetaType<QProcess::ProcessError>("QProcess::ProcessError");` before the connection.

So final version is:

```
qRegisterMetaType<QProcess::ProcessError>("QProcess::ProcessError");
QProcess process;
connect(&process, static_cast<void (QProcess::*)(QProcess::ProcessError)>
        (&QProcess::error), this , [=](QProcess::ProcessError pError) {
    qWarning() << "error " << pError;
},Qt::QueuedConnection);
process.start("MyProgram");
bool launched = process.startDetached("example");
```