# SIGNAL & SLOT macros in Qt : what do they do?

Tags: qt, macros, signals, slot

I'm a beginner in Qt and trying to understand the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros. When I'm learning to use the `connect` method to bind the signal and slot, I found the tutorials on Qt's official reference page uses:

```
connect(obj1, SIGNAL(signal(int)), obj2, SLOT(slot()))
```

However, this also works very well:

```
connect(obj1, &Obj1::signal, obj2, &Obj2::slot)
```

So what exactly do the macros `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` do? Do they just look for the signal in the class the object belongs to and return the address of it?

Then why do most programmers use these macros instead of using `&Obj1::signal` since the latter appears to be simpler and you don't need to change the code if the parameters of the signal function change?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The use of the `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros used to be the only way to make connections, before Qt 5. The connection is made at runtime and require signal and slots to be marked in the header. For example:

```
Class MyClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    signals:
        void Signal();

    slots:
        void ASlotFunction();
};
```

To avoid repetition, the way in which it works is described [in the QT 4 documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html).

The signal and slot mechanism is part of the C++ extensions that are provided by Qt and make use of the [Meta Object Compiler (moc)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html#moc).

[This](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/why-moc.html) explains why signals and slots use the moc.

The second connect method is much improved as the functions specified can be checked at the time of compilation, not runtime. In addition, by using the address of a function, you can refer to any class function, not just those in the section marked *slots:*

The [documentation was updated for Qt 5](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html).

In addition, there's a good blog post about the Qt 4 connect workings [here](http://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html) and Qt 5 [here](http://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work-part2-qt5.html).

Answer (score 6):

Addition to the first answer.

> what exactly did the macro SIGNAL and SLOT do

Almost nothing. Look at the `qobjectdefs.h`:

```
# define SLOT(a)     "1"#a
# define SIGNAL(a)   "2"#a
```

It just adds `1` or `2`. It means that next code is valid and works as expected:

```
QObject *obj = new QObject;
connect(obj,"2objectNameChanged(QString)",this,"1show()");//suppose this is a pointer to a QDialog subclass
obj->setObjectName("newNAme");
```

> why do most programmers use these macros instead of using like
>   &Obj1::signal

- Because these macros work not only in Qt5.
- Because with these macros there is no complexity with overloaded
  signals ([it can make your code very dirty and it is really not a simple thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464822/c2665-qobjectconnect-none-of-the-3-overloads-could-convert-all-the-argume/31468973#31468973))
- Because with new syntax you sometimes need to use specific
  disconnects

[More details here.](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax)

Comment: Did you really meant to say *"these macros work not only in Qt5"*? Or something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes, because macros-way works in Qt4 and Qt5, but new-way via pointer-to-method works in Qt5 only, so that's why I wrote like that, devs who works with legacy old code can't use Qt5, so they can't use new way, so they use old way which "work not only in Qt5"

Answer (score 2):

To complete [TheDarkKnight's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31589435/signal-slot-macro-in-qt/31589638#31589638), it is an excellent practice to refactor legacy code that is using the old Qt 4 SIGNAL and SLOT macros to Qt 5's new syntax using function address.

Suddenly, connection error will appear at compile time instead of at runtime! It's very easy to make a Qt 4 connection error as any spelling mistake will result in such an error. Plus, the name of the function must be the fully qualified name, i.e preceded with the full namespace if any.

Another benefit is the ability to use a lambda for the slot function, which can reduce need of a named function if the slot body is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

These macros just convert their parameters to signal/slot-specific strings. The [Differences between String-Based and Functor-Based Connections](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html) can be found in the docs. In short:

> String-based:
>
> - Type checking is done at Run-time
> - Can connect signals to slots which have more arguments than the signal (using default parameters)
> - Can connect C++ functions to QML functions
>
> Functor-based:
>
> - Type checking is done at Compile-time
> - Can perform implicit type conversions
> - Can connect signals to lambda expressions