# In QT, can we have two slots with same name but different arguments?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have two signals with same name coming from two different `classes` `A` and `B` into `class C`. Let `void SomeSignal()` is a signal from `class A` without any argument. I have another signal `void SomeSignal(int)` coming from another class.

I need to handle these signals in two different ways in `class C`. Can I make two slots `void SomeSignal()` and `void SomeSignal(int)` in `class C`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is valid. But if you do this, you need to handling connecting to the signals/slots differently than the normal way when using the Qt 5 connect syntax.

Look at the following question and answer on how to handle [connecting to overloaded signals and slots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16794695/991000)

So in short, connect as:

```
connect(a, &A::SomeSignal, this, static_cast<void (C::*)(void)>(&C::SomeSlot));
connect(b, &B::SomeSignal, this, static_cast<void (C::*)(int)>(&C::SomeSlot));
```

Or if you are using Qt 5.7 use the [qOverload](http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.7/qtglobal.html#qOverload) helper functions.

*Edit*: Using explicit template arguments as @TobySpeight pointed out below:

```
QObject::connect<void(A::*)(), void(C::*)()>(&a, &A::SomeSignal, &c, &C::SomeSlot);
QObject::connect<void(B::*)(int), void(C::*)(int)>(&b, &B::SomeSignal, &c, &C::SomeSlot);
```

- *Seems like one must specify both template arguments to connect since the slot is overloaded.*

Comment: I think it's safer to [provide explicit template arguments to `connect<>()`](/a/37302949) than to `static_cast` the member pointer.

Comment: @TobySpeight I was not aware of this syntax, thanks. I can see how it can be deduced when looking at the implementation of `QObject::connect` but it seems like it is undocumented, especially when looking at the documentation on [QObject::connect()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-3) (the docs hide the use of templates)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but if you are handling different stuff coming from completely different classes it's clearer to name those slots differently (remember that there's no relation required between the signals names and the linked slots names).

Comment: Thanks @Matteo Italia.

Comment: It's simply overloading.