# Connecting Signals to c++11 lambdas in QT5

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I tried to connect a QDoubleSpinBox Signal to a c++11 lamda:

```
QObject::connect(sbox_roughness, &QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged,
               [=]() { std::cout << "value changed" << std::endl; });
```

This is giving me:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Game::connect(QDoubleSpinBox*&, <unresolved overloaded function type>, Game::initGui()::<lambda()>)’
                [=]() { std::cout << "value changed" << std::endl; });
note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘const char*’
```

I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794695/connecting-overloaded-signals-and-slots-in-qt-5?noredirect=1&lq=1):

```
QObject::connect(sbox_roughness, static_cast<void (QDoubleSpinBox::*)(int)>(
                                   &QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),
               [=]() { std::cout << "value changed" << std::endl; });
```

giving me:

```
error: no matches converting function ‘valueChanged’ to type ‘void (class QDoubleSpinBox::*)(int)’
                                    &QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
QDoubleSpinBox spinbox;

QObject::connect(&spinbox, &QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged,
                 []() { qDebug() << "value changed"; });
```

This fails because `QDoubleSpinBox` has two `valueChanged` signals, and it's impossible to decide which one you wanted to connect to here.

```
QObject::connect(&spinbox, static_cast<void (QDoubleSpinBox::*)(int)>(
                                  &QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),
                []() {  qDebug() << "value changed"; });
```

This fails because `QDoubleSpinBox` does not have a `valueChanged(int)` signal.

This will work:

```
QObject::connect(&spinbox, static_cast<void (QDoubleSpinBox::*)(double)>(
                                  &QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),
                []() {  qDebug() << "value changed"; });

QObject::connect(&spinbox, static_cast<void (QDoubleSpinBox::*)(const QString &)>(
                                  &QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),
                []() {  qDebug() << "value changed"; });
```

Comment: Of cause it it doesn't work with:    (QDoubleSpinBox::*)(**int**)>(                     &QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged). Sorry for overseeing this! Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

You faced arguments missmatch. Should be like this:

```
QObject::connect(sbox_roughness, static_cast<void(QDoubleSpinBox::*)(double)>(&QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged),
           [=](double val) { std::cout << "value changed" << std::endl; });
```

Comment: Your answer has changed them to the one I have.