# c++ - Functional with operator()

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

Let say I have the following code:

```
template<typename T> Matrix{
  private:
    int nr;
    std::vector<T> data;
  public:
    T& operator()(const int& j, const int& k){
    return this->mat.at(j+k*nr);}

    const T& operator()(const int& j, const int& k) const {
    return this->mat.at(j+k*nr);}
};
```

At some point I need to create a function pointer associated to `const T& operator()(const int& j) const` to use it as an argument in another function. Using `functional`, I tried:

```
//#include<functional>
function<const double&(const Matrix<double>&, const int&, const int&)> coef=&Matrix<double>::operator();
```

and I have the following error:

```
 no viable conversion from '<overloaded function type>' to 'function<const double &(const
  Matrix<double> &, const int &, const int &)>
```

I cannot get it to work and it is pretty hard to find informations on `function`, since the name is quite used...

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comment section, it is not a duplicate and I don't think I should you use `bind`. I am just trying to apply the last example in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/function/ where they add a reference argument in the function pointer for a member function. The difference here is that my function member is an operator and I have not succeeded in doing the same as in the example. So, is there a syntax problem in what I am doing ? or may there is a subtlety with operators ?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the linked question, it is about overload resolution and address-of-member

Comment: @Rakete1111 I have seen it. But I don't understand why I should `bind`. I added `const Matrix<double>&` to the template argument used in the instantiation of `coef`. It actually work with usual methods (like in the last example of http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/function/)

Comment: `const double&(Matrix<double::*member)(const int &, const int&) = &Matrix<double>::operator(); std::function<...> coef = member;` will work. Similar is going on in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794695/connecting-overloaded-signals-and-slots-in-qt-5

Comment: @PierreMarchand Because it is a member function, you have to add an instance to call it one or make the function take an instance of any class. You don't have to use `std::bind`, a lambda works fine and is better anyways.

Comment: @Rakete1111 he's binding to the right function type, the problem is the non-const overload

Comment: @Caleth You sure? I thought that the first parameter has to be a pointer to the class, not a reference.

Comment: It's bullet 1 of pointer-to-member-function in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Callable, not bullet 3. That is, a `std::function<Ret(Class&)>` is more general than `std::function<Ret(Class*)>`, in that it can be called with either pointers or references

Comment: As I said, in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/function/ there is an example where they use a reference for a member function. So, my question can be marked as not a duplicate ?

Comment: My question is still marked as duplicate and I have already edited it, what can I do ?