# Qt Version checking and QOverload not defined in scope

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, cmake, ubuntu-16.04

Good day all

**Background:**

I am at the point of building and test-deploying my application on debian systems, however I have run into some trouble

My application uses `QOverload` for the [QNetworkReply](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html), as suggested by the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#error) page.

An example usage is (from doc page):

```
connect(networkReply, QOverload<QNetworkReply::NetworkError>::of(&QNetworkReply::error),
    [=](QNetworkReply::NetworkError code){ /* ... */ });
```

or another usage found in my application:

```
# header
QButtonGroup *grpProtocol;
QMetaObject::Connection conProtocol

# implementation
conProtocol = QObject::connect(ui->grpProtocol, QOverload<QAbstractButton *, bool>::of(&QButtonGroup::buttonToggled), [this](){
    //do some action when a radio button in a QButtonGroup is toggled
});
```

**Problem:**

When calling `make` on my application, `make` complains with an error:

```
mainwindow.cpp: In member function ‘void MainWindow::initConnectors()’:
mainwindow.cpp:462:53: error: ‘QOverload’ was not declared in this scope
     conProtocol = QObject::connect(ui->grpProtocol, QOverload<QAbstractButton *, bool>::of(&QButtonGroup::buttonToggled), [this](){
                                                     ^
mainwindow.cpp:462:79: error: expected primary-expression before ‘*’ token
     conProtocol = QObject::connect(ui->grpProtocol, QOverload<QAbstractButton *, bool>::of(&QButtonGroup::buttonToggled), [this](){
                                                                               ^
mainwindow.cpp:462:80: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
     conProtocol = QObject::connect(ui->grpProtocol, QOverload<QAbstractButton *, bool>::of(&QButtonGroup::buttonToggled), [this](){
                                                                                ^
mainwindow.cpp:462:82: error: expected primary-expression before ‘bool’
     conProtocol = QObject::connect(ui->grpProtocol, QOverload<QAbstractButton *, bool>::of(&QButtonGroup::buttonToggled), [this](){
                                                                                  ^
Makefile:476: recipe for target 'mainwindow.o' failed
```

Now, this leads me to check when `QOverload` is found and include the header.

[QOverload](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload) can be found in `qglobal.h` but was only introduced in QT 5.7

- Qoverload requires the use of C++11
- Or qOverload, using C++14

The problem is that Ubuntu 16.04 uses Qt version 5.5:

```
qtchooser -print-env
QT_SELECT="default"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

**What I tried:**

I resolved to using [preprocessor directives to do the version check](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#QT_VERSION_CHECK)ing for me.

```
#if QT_VERSION <= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 7, 0)
    qDebug(mainclient) << "Adding connector for settings prefered connection protocol";
    conProtocol = QObject::connect(ui->grpProtocol, QOverload<QAbstractButton *, bool>::of(&QButtonGroup::buttonToggled), [this](){
        // my code here which which handles events
    });
#endif
```

However, the above error of `make` resulted with the preprocessor directive included. i.e. Including the Qt version check still threw the QOverload out of scope.

**Question:**

Put simply, what did I do wrong? Why, with a specific QT version check set, does make ignore this and build everything still?

**Update with possible alternative solutions**

1. Eliminate the `QOverload` entirely and replace with pre QT 5.7 code which will make my code slightly bulkier and some redundant code (possible)
2. Add the header file to my application files and include it only if the system has a Qt version < Qt5.7 (considered very bad practise)

Comment: Probably forgot to include some headers?

Comment: @vahancho in `Qt5.7+` there is a `qglobal.h` header where the `QOverload` function is found. Pre `Qt5.7`, there simply is no `QOverload` function as it didn't exist before then, thus there is no header to include

Comment: as suggested by an answer (now delete): `#if (QT_VERSION <= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 7, 0))` doesn't work (adding the parenthesis)

Comment: I deleted the answer 'cause I'm not sure, just checking (and it could be creator, btw).

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o no. I uploaded the source to my github account, and pulled onto a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 LTS VM install and built from there. So no, it is not QT-Creator causing the issue. I will mention, that on my dev machine, the application compiles without a problem. My dev machine uses `QMake 3.1` with `QT version 5.9.3`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `static_cast` to replace `QOverload`:

```
connect(networkReply, static_cast<void (QNetworkReply::*)(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)>(&QNetworkReply::error),
    [=](QNetworkReply::NetworkError code){ /* ... */ });
```

from here: [Connecting overloaded signals and slots in Qt 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794695/connecting-overloaded-signals-and-slots-in-qt-5)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in logical expression here:

```
#if QT_VERSION <= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 7, 0)
```

Which basically says "enable following block if the version is **less or equal** than 5.7". And Qt 5.5 meets this criteria.