# Using Qt5 new signal-slot syntax to connect QSpinBox::valueChanged

Tags: qt, qt5, signals-slots

When I used `connect()` to connect a `&QRadioButton::toggled` signal with a `void`-return type function, all went well:

```
QRadioButton *radioCrack = new QRadioButton;
QObject::connect(radioCrack, &QRadioButton::toggled, updateCeasarCrack);
```

My function (which is placed above):

```
void updateCeasarCrack()
{
    cerr << "done";
}
```

But when I tried to do the same for `&QSpinBox::valueChanged`:

```
QSpinBox *keyBox = new QSpinBox;
QObject::connect(keyBox, &QSpinBox::valueChanged, updateCeasarCrack);
```

I got an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'connect'
```

Full error image :

[image: error]

Did I misunderstood something with the way `connect()` work? I've tried googling and came up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16794695/connecting-overloaded-signals-and-slots-in-qt-5), but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Sources : https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Comment: Please see the documentation for [`QSpinBox::valueChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qspinbox.html#valueChanged).  Specifically the use of `QOverload` (or [`qOverload`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload)).

Comment: Oh, I missed that completely. Thanks @G.M.